# Upload files ONLINE in the FTP (script in PHP)

Tags: php, ftp

I want to prepare a script in php so I can upload files online ( The files are in some websites with login and password) directly to my FTP !

let me explain to you the operation!
There's some Suppliers of my shop who provides the products of my shop !
Everyday I connect to their sites , I enter an URL and then My login and password and I upload some product files from their site to my local environment and then copy this files in my FTP ! 
So what I want is doing that automatically so I don't have to do thant manually ! 
Any idea??

Comment: So you download the files from their website (using webbrowser)? We do not know anything about it. Maybe they have some API to automate the download. If not, you have to imitate the login HTTP request. But we cannot help you without knowing the system.

Comment: Anyway your question would better fit to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl All what they have in their website is once I Enter the URL of the website I got a form I should enter my login and password ! then it will redirect me to another page which I find a button download I choose CSV file and then I find it in My local environment

Comment: Consider re-phrasing your question to "how to automate html login form and http download"? And retag your question accordingly. Thought I'd say there surely is a question on this already.

Answer (score 0):

May be you just have to write some cron job on your machine for ncftp, for example?
Try adding something like this:

```
 6 8 * * * your_user_name ncftpget -u your_user_at_server -p your_pass server /local/path *remote_file_mask* ; ncftpput -u your_user_at_server -p your_pass server /remote/path /local/path/*remote_file_mask*
```

to your /etc/crontab

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve it using php ftp function. for more information please refer following [http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php][1]

[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php link